# CKEDITOR 4 & Postback .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

Am trying to look at JavaScript richtextboxes and currently looking at CKEDITOR version 4 for a webform c#.

My question is, every time I do postback I lose any styles I've done. Is there a way of storing the changes or stop CK from clearing the textarea ?

Comment: I happen to use a previous version of that editor with MojoPortal and I don't have that problem. I'm curious to see the resolution for the OP's problem, though.

Comment: do u have any javascript errors in page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to make the `textarea` runat server
 example :

`<textarea class="ckeditor" runat="server" name="editor1" ></textarea>`

making html control `runat=server` will store its values in a viewstates between postbacks

**Edit:**

I've added these refrences to get my example work

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ckeditor/styles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="ckeditor/contents.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. If you add runat the CKEditor functions disappear and your left with normal textarea.

Comment: actually this works for me after adding `runat=server` , do u miss `js` file refrence , check edit above

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks for your reply. I needed to set ClientIDMode="Static": <asp:TextBox ID="editor1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> thanks for your help